# Split column values to multiple columns dynamically

Tags: mysql

is there anybody who knows how to achieve this, please see the image below, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How many columns do you have? Will it always be the same number?

Comment: Yes, I got that bit - but how many comma separated values will there be - is it constant? BTW, could you please delete your second post/clarification. You can always edit your own question (the best way of adding information). Then let me know by putting @Vérace (@<user_name> in the body of your reply!

Comment: The number of comma separated values i is not exact, sometimes 5, 10 or even 31 or more its depend on the user. Thank you for your explanation on how to post

Comment: Is there a maximum possible number of values?

Comment: @Vérace let say 100 is the possible maximum number,

Comment: Hi @Vérace did you figured out a bit?

Comment: Dynamic generation of Pivot code:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to code something like that into a stored procedure but it is not straightforward. MySQL does not have a PIVOT operator that dynamically generates columns, so the closest you could get is something like this Q&A below. Basically, you create CASE statements that extract each part of your string.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table